# python matplotlib.pyplot and numpy problems

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following problem. I want to evaluate the following function

```
def sigLinZ(self,val,omega):
    A = 1
    C = 0 
    D = 1 

    B =1./(omega*val*1j)

    return np.asmatrix(np.array([[A,B],[C,D]]))
```

in such a way that I can use it in pyplot in such a way:

```
omega = numpy.arange(0,100,1)
y = classInstance.sigLinZ(12,omega)
plt.plot(omega,y)
```

but this does not work. Python says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "testImpedanz.py", line 132, in test6_lineImpedanz
    print "neue Matrix: ",  lineImpe.sigLinZ('C',lineImpe.C(),np.array([600e6,300e6]))
  File "/afs/physnet.uni-hamburg.de/users/ap_h/pgwozdz/Dokumente/PythonSkriptsPHD/ImpedanzCalculation.py", line 350, in sigLinZ
    return np.mat(np.array([[A,B],[C,D]]))
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I know for numpy functions this procedure works just fine but for my function it does not work at all.

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to insert an array into the element of matrix in your definition of `omega` that you're passing into the method. Either you need to iterate over `omega` passing each element to `sigLinZ`separately, or you need to re-write `sigLinZ` to handle the array and return something like a list of matrices or 3D array.

Answer (score 1):

First, the problem has nothing to do with pylab and is only numpy related. It fails on the line:

```
return np.asmatrix(np.array([[A,B],[C,D]]))
```

And actually fails here

```
np.array([[A,B],[C,D]])
```

The reason why it doesn't work can be determined from the error message and the shape of the objects. When you pass `omega` with a shape of

```
print omega
>>> (100,)
```

and try to put it into an object of size `2x2`, `[[A,B],[C,D]]` it will indeed complain about

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Did you intend to return a scalar value from the function `sigLinZ`? I'm inferring that since you are trying to do a simple `plt.plot` command with the result.

**Edit:** If you really want a matrix of matrices, you need to make the other entries the same size as `B`

```
def sigLinZ(val,omega):
  B = 1./(omega*val*1j)
  A = 1*np.ones(B.shape)
  C = 0*np.ones(B.shape)
  D = 1*np.ones(B.shape)
  return np.array([[A,B],[C,D]])
```

Which gives a shape of `(2,2,100)`, i.e. the last index sets the array count of a bunch of 2x2 matrices. *Sidenote*, as it stands, `B` divides by zero.

Comment: The problem is that I need a matrix here. After calling sigLinZ a few times I am deriving a function out of the matrix entries which shall be used to fit some data points. But this breaks at this point because I obviously can not call this function as it is expected in  scipy.optimize.curve_fit. I just coosed this point in the code because it is simple.

Comment: @PaulGwozdz I think the edit supplies what you are looking for. Let me know if you are still having any problems and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Ok this returns a 2x2 Matrix. The elements are arrays. What I want is for every omega I pass as a list i want a 2x2 matrix were every entry is a complex number. The behaviour shall be the same as x=np.range(0,10,1) and y = np.sin(x) where y is then a list conrtaining the values of the sin function. I want a list of 2X2 matrizes that depend on omega which I want to pass as a list

Comment: @PaulGwozdz "Ok this returns a 2x2 Matrix", not quite. The shape `(2,2,100)` shows it returns a LIST of 2x2 matrices where the index `(i,j,k)` refers to the kth matrix with elements i,j.